# How to set a character after x lenght in a string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, uuid

I'm trying to create a script that automatically replaces a minecraft uuid from `b75243c9b8534269b885b036875a627c` (without dashes) to `b75243c9-b853-4269-b885-b036875a627c` (with dashes) in python. But I have no idea how. Can you help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A quick and easy, albeit not as performative, way is to use [uuid.UUID](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.UUID) class and pass in your string as an argument

```
import uuid
my_uuid = uuid.UUID('b75243c9b8534269b885b036875a627c')
print(str(my_uuid))
>>> b75243c9-b853-4269-b885-b036875a627c
```

Comment: I get this error: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'UUID'

Comment: @Joachim Based that error, it would seem you have a `dict` variable named `uuid`. That is shadowing the module `uuid`. Try naming it something different

Comment: Despite the mark as duplicate, this answer is better for OPs use. (More explicit code!)

Answer (score 0):

```
uuid = b75243c9b8534269b885b036875a627c

uuid = uuid[0:8] + "-" + uuid[8:12] + "-" + uuid[12:16] + "-" + 
            uuid[16:20] + "-" + uuid[20:]
```

As strings in python are immutable, you cannot insert a character in between.  You can slice the given string and add ' - '.